# Does the SA80 appear in Battlefield 3?

Tags: battlefield-3

Does the SA80 assault rifle appear in Battlefield 3? If so, what classes can use it, and how do I acquire it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SA80 (Also known as the L85A2 Assault Rifle) is available in the Back to Karkand expansion pack for the Assault class.

See [here](http://bf3blog.com/battlefield-3-l85a2/) for a list of statistics and unlocks for this weapon.